# regex detecting "more than one" of entitiy

Tags: java, regex

I have strings of the following kind:

```
asdf:0123-456-789:USB0::0x1234::0x9ABC::0123-456-789::INSTR
```

First, there is the name `asdf` followed by the serial `0123-456-789` followed by the address string `USB0::0x1234::0x9ABC::0123-456-789::INSTR`. The format is

```
name:serial:addr
```

**I want to extract the name, the serial and the address into single Strings**. The address can also contain `::` so I can not just `String#split(String regex)` it (or can I?). My idea was to use a regex expression that captures these three entities. I am very new to regex.

I am using Java:

```
String input = "asdf:0123-456-789:USB0::0x1234::0x9ABC::0123-456-789::INSTR";
// name
Matcher nameMatcher = Pattern.compile("[0-9a-zA-Z]+").matcher(input);
nameMatcher.find();
String name = nameMatcher.group();
// serial
Matcher serialMatcher = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{9}-[0-9]{4}").matcher(input);
serialMatcher.find();
String serial = serialMatcher.group();
// address
Matcher addrMatcher = Pattern.compile("[0-9a-zA-Z[:]{2}-]+").matcher(input);
addrMatcher.find();
String address= addrMatcher.group();
System.out.println(name + " / " + serial + " / " + address);

// result:
// asdf, 012-012345678-0123, asdf:012-012345678-01234:USB0::0x1234::0x9ABC::012-012345678-01234::INSTR
```

This works good for name and serial, but not for the address (it captures the whole input string instead of just the address). The problem is that I only want to allow `::` and not `:` but it does not work as I intended. Is there a nice way to match this or is this all way too complicated? If so, can you show me a different approach?

EDIT: I just found a good enough solution for me:

```
String input = "asdf:012-012345678-01234:USB0::0x1234::0x9ABC::012-012345678-01234::INSTR";
String[] asdf = input.split(":");
String name = asdf[0];
String serial = asdf[1];
String address = asdf[2];
for (int i = 3; i < asdf.length; i++)
  address += ":" + asdf[i];
Log.i(name + ", " + serial + ", " + address);
```

But the question remains (out of curiosity and to learn something).

Comment: @Nishant This works for name and serial, but not for the address, which I have to puzzle together with this approach (see my edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String info="asdf:0123-456-789:USB0::0x1234::0x9ABC::0123-456-789::INSTR";
String[] array=info.split(":", 3);//split only in 3 parts

System.out.println("name="+array[0]);
System.out.println("serial="+array[1]);
System.out.println("addr="+array[2]);
```

output

```
name = asdf
serial = 0123-456-789
addr = USB0::0x1234::0x9ABC::0123-456-789::INSTR
```

Comment: I am accepting this answer, because it's the one I use now. Nevertheless, the other answers were quite helpful to me too.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

```
input.split("(?<!:):(?!:)")
```

which basically looks around the : character to make sure that there are no other : characters next to it.

Comment: That works very well. Although I don't really get why. I don't understand the `?<!` and `?!` before the `:`.

Comment: They are lookaheads and lookbehinds. The constructs go like `(?<=X)` which roughly means "check behind this to see if X is not present" and `(?!X)` "check ahead of this to see if X is not present". So in your case you only need to exchange `X` with `:`.

Answer (score 1):

You could match the address on its own with the regex `([\w-])+(::([\w-]+))+`

```
([\w-])+    one or more word (alphanumeric) or hyphen characters ...
(           ... followed by ...
::          ... two colons ...
([\w-]+)    ... with one or more word (alphanumeric) or hyphen characters ...
)+          ... at least one more time
```

Comment: Cool, thats what I was looking for in the first place. Thanks for the detailed explanation.